# Putting the output into a table

Tags: linux, grep

I know this is a FAQ but I've already read multiple pages about this and I can't get it to work. I'm using the `grep` command to locate a range of values from three different text files.

Command line:

```
grep -o "201[1-4].[0-9][ -9]" file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

Output:

```
file1.txt:2012.69
file1.txt:2013.44
file2.txt:2013.17
file2.txt:2012.6    
file2.txt:2013.75
file2.txt:2013.08
file3.txt:2013.54
file3.txt:2013.9
```

I want the output to have the names of the three files as the first row (header) and then all of the values found to be in each column. I think the problem is that I am unable to predict how many rows I would need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` to join the output of `grep` to one row per file, then transpose with `csvtool` and optional `column -nt` to make the output nice (note, that `-n` is a Debian extension and might not be available for your platform).

```bsh
grep -o "201[1-4].[0-9][ -9]" file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt \
| awk -F: '
  {
    if (!s[$1]){ s[$1]=$2 }
    else { s[$1]=s[$1]","$2 }
  }
  END {
    for (f in s){ print f","s[f] }
  }' \
| csvtool transpose -u " " - \
| column -nt
```

Output:

```
file1.txt  file3.txt  file2.txt
2012.69    2013.54    2013.17
2013.44    2013.9     2012.6
                      2013.75
                      2013.08
```

You might need to install `csvtool`.

Comment: make it `column -nt`, then it shows as it should.

Comment: thanks, updated.

Comment: `-n` only works like that with BSD `column`, not with the version in `util-linux` :-(. The latter is what’s installed on Fedora & co.

Comment: as the whole column thing is optional, I'll leave it with that note ;-)

Comment: You could transpose with awk, too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1729980 ---I was tinkering with datamash and that.

Comment: sure, you could do the whole thing in `awk`, but I like to make use of available tools ;-) I was looking for `join` to do the `awk` part, but it always needs 2 files :-(

Comment: Even if you don't want to do the transpose in awk, piping grep into awk is still a Useless Use Of Grep.  e.g. `awk '/201[1-4]\.[0-9]+/ { if (!s[FILENAME]){ s[FILENAME]=$1 } else { s[FILENAME]=s[FILENAME]"\t"$1 } }; END { for (f in s){ print f"\t"s[f] } }' file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt | datamash --no-strict --filler="" transpose | column -nt`.    I'm using tabs & datamash here (rather than commas and csvtool) because I don't see any need to produce comma separated output and then convert it to tab-separated.  Also, because `datamash` is a general purpose tool which is worth learning/using.

Comment: I agree that that `grep` can be integrated in `awk` but I just extended OPs approach ... But preferring `datamash` over `csvtool` is really a matter of choice. `datamash` is more advanced and I never had the need to learn it yet. Where do you see any comma-separated output ? In general: thousand ways lead to Rome, and if you think you have a better one, you should post an answer.

Comment: Your awk script outputs commas, then csvtool outputs tabs.    As for csvtool vs datamash, I prefer to use tools that have man pages. and other documentation.   csvtool only has `--help` (but at least it does the sane thing and prints that to stdout, rather than stderr like some programs).  I also have a strong preference for general purpose tools over single-purpose tools.   datamash can process data in various forms in many ways.  csvtool can do some basic stuff with comma (or other separator) delimited data.