# How to calculate n values in a column and the overall average?

Tags: linux, text-processing, text-formatting, checksum, load-average

I would really appreciate some help with this as I am relativity new to Linux. I'm using `grep` but I also want an average of all of my extracted values (irrespective of which column they are in) and the number of values (n) that were extracted from each file (and put into each column).

Command:

```
grep -o "201[1-4].[0-9][ -9]" file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt \ | awk -F: '
  {
    if (!s[$1]){ s[$1]=$2 }
    else { s[$1]=s[$1]","$2 }
  }
  END {
    for (f in s){ print f","s[f] }
  }' | csvtool transpose -u " " - | column -nt
```

Current output:

```
file1.txt  file3.txt  file2.txt
2013.17    2012.69    2013.54
2012.6     2013.44    2013.9
2013.12    2012.64    2013.66
2012.76    2013.11    2013.44
2013.75    2012.6     2013.89
2013.08    2012.41    2013.62
           2012.41    2013.41
           2013.2
```

There are always three columns but the number of rows can't be predicted.

Example:

```
file1.txt  file3.txt  file2.txt
1          2          3
2          1          1
                      2

n=2        n=2        n=3                      
Average: 1.714
```

Example of the content I'm using:

file1:

```
2896.79 2897.65 2898.82 2012.69 2013.44 2897.4  2896.79 2012.64 2896.71 2217.4  2013.11 2012.6  2012.41 2012.41 2013.2  2897.12 2896.61 2896.35 2896.85 2896.26 2896.72
2913.91 2914.41 2914.27 2329.68 2329.71 2914.15 2914.32 2321.19 2914.02 2329.32 2896.49 2025.55 2328.84 2328.98 2329.1  2913.96 2913.48 2913.36 2913.97 2913.46 2913.71
2925.09 2925.58 2926.69 2401.39 2897.65 2925.77 2925.55 2328.96 2924.86 2897.19 2913.95 2029.61 2896.86 2896.93 2764.59 2925.18 2924.96 2924.68 2925.03 2924.18 2924.72
2933.54 2933.91 3196.19 2897.73 2914.79 3314.12 3016.04 2400.29 3015.62 2914.03 2925.09 2897.07 2913.69 2914.41 2897.38 2934.31 3058.51 3015.26 2934.32 2932.55 2933.38
2952.71 2953.49 3223.9  2914.91 2926.03 3321.3  3066.1  2896.71 3065.91 2925.14 2934.16 2914.04 2924.74 2925.54 2914.6  2952.92 3065.18 3065.74 2953.23 3072.91 2952.84
3016.02 3016.4  3249.51 2925.73 2932.82 3373.04 3073.91 2913.87 3073.65 2953.29 2952.94 2925.78 2952.15 2933.65 2925.67 3015.76 3073.21 3072.94 3065.81 3222.86 3015.45
3065.42 3059.27 3313.84 2953.72 2953.17 3444.15 3081.47 2925.02 3192.84 3015.73 3015.47 2953.12 3015.35 2953.29 2953.84 3073.71 3223.42 3080.34 3073.98 3312.09 3059.03
```

file2:

```
2013.17 2012.6  2013.12 2036.82 2037.29 2036.53 2036.44 2032.6  2032.88 2012.76 2037.57 2037.26 2037.5  2042.89 2038.1  2013.75 2037.73 2038    2037.93 2033.5  2033.26 2013.08
2033.07 2033.03 2032.99 2042.08 2042.15 2042.14 2041.82 2036.84 2036.88 2033.27 2042.66 2042.65 2042.61 2461.68 2042.94 2037.45 2042.99 2042.96 2043.04 2037.29 2037.32 2033.44
2037.25 2037.27 2037.26 2080.15 2080.48 2080.35 2079.99 2042.18 2042.22 2037.31 2461.16 2080.81 2080.72 2465.94 2461.39 2043    2081.13 2081.08 2081.26 2042.62 2042.63 2037.55
2042.56 2042.49 2042.41 2464.77 2465.3  2465.08 2460.36 2053.03 2465.1  2042.58 2465.84 2461.76 2460.66 2473.93 2466.23 2461.58 2461.48 2461.6  2466.06 2053.48 2053.35 2042.68
2053.26 2053.42 2053.79 2480.18 2473.43 2472.84 2464.91 2080.37 2480.47 2058.27 2473.22 2465.78 2465.78 2482.02 2474.04 2466.07 2466.05 2466.01 2474.01 2080.88 2080.75 2053.24
2076.01 2059.33 2058.08 2500.19 2481.17 2480.7  2472.76 2460.1  2529.24 2076.3  2481.38 2473.76 2473.51 2501.38 2482.1  2473.97 2474.02 2473.99 2482.05 2276.73 2276.52 2058.42
2080.83 2075.97 2075.97 2529.14 2529.55 2529.28 2481.04 2465.12 2537.59 2080.44 2489.75 2481.63 2481.37 2525.17 2490.26 2482.1  2481.98 2481.96 2501.93 2465.52 2465.58 2076.22
2250.64 2080.54 2080.49 2537.07 2536.95 2537.65 2487.59 2473    2619.65 2276.27 2496.5  2500.38 2489.45 2530.2  2502.23 2525.03 2490.46 2501.06 2530.44 2500.93 2481.26 2080.85
2276.67 2118.71 2275.92 2635.42 2547.03 2544.73 2503.45 2480.94 2636.12 2465.35 2500.25 2524.95 2524.14 2538.07 2524.69 2530.47 2530.45 2524.9  2538.6  2529.88 2500.92 2276.34
```

file3:

```
2207.2  2003.43 6628.01 2013.54 2013.9  2914.93 2003.72 3315.09 2013.66 2013.44 2147.76 2147.67 2207.45 2147.93 2013.89 2013.62 2008.56 2914.99 6632.04
2252.13 2036.51         2147.79 2036.93 2926.08 2013.41 5833.85 2037.51 2037.41 2206.79 2207.16 2898.47 2207.22 2037.11 2147.77 2037.9  3060    
2639.52 2120.66         2206.81 2147.77 3016.02 2036.57 6630.91 2147.94 2147.93 2914.59 2914.66 2915.5  2898.31 2207.46 2206.73 2147.96 3225.13 
2829.69 2147.96         2329.47 2207.1  3059.21 2147.81         2207.22 2207.15 3015.96 3058.98 2926.66 2915.11 2898.69 2329.31 2166.65 3314.22 
2914.74 2206.87         2897.84 2252.53 3225    2329.91         2329.35 2329.69 3031.21 3224.88 3059.82 2926.17 2915.3  2897.89 2207.42 5833.23 
3015.61 2252.38         2914.72 2329.72 3265.74 2897.86         2897.85 2897.81 3058.98 3265.62 3225.63 3059.46 2926.66 2914.67 2253.44 6034.36 
3030.72 2329.24         2925.98 2897.89 3305.35 2914.99         2915    2914.72 3077.57 3305.36 3266.57 3225.4  3016.03 2925.65 2330.06 6121.01
```

Comment: It would have been helpful if you had posted that data in your [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/546714/364705), that would have shortened the way to a solution.

Comment: I do apologise, I was unfamiliar with how to phrase questions on here as I didn't want to add lots of detail.

Comment: No need to apologize, it is an easy trap to step in :-) Just beware of the [XY Problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your actual problem in one step:

```bash
$ grep -o '201[1-4].[0-9]\+' file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt \
| datamash --sort -t: -g1 count 2 mean 2 

file1.txt:8:2012.8125
file2.txt:6:2013.08
file3.txt:7:2013.6371428571
```

- `grep` gets the values from the files,
- `datamash` counts the items and calculates averages by file.

Now you have one line per file: `filename:n:average`

Easier, right?

To get the average over all the files, drop the grouping:

```bash
grep -o '201[1-4].[0-9]\+' file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt \
| datamash --sort -t: mean 2

2013.1638095238
```

If you need the pretty-printed tabular output, try something like this:

```bash
$ cat mktable.sh
#!/bin/bash
myfiles="$@"

trap "rm ${myfiles//txt/txt.tempfile}" EXIT SIGTERM SIGINT

declare -A count

for f in $myfiles ; do
  # write the tempfile AND get the linecount simultaneously
    count[$f]="$(grep -o '201[1-4].[0-9]\+' "$f" | tee ${f}.tempfile | wc -l)"
  sed -i "1i $f" ${f}.tempfile        # write header
  sed -i "2i ---------" ${f}.tempfile # write header
done

( paste ${myfiles//txt/txt.tempfile} ;
 for item in $myfiles ; do echo -n '--------- '; done; echo
 for item in $myfiles ; do echo -n "n=${count[$item]} " ; done ; echo ;
 for item in $myfiles ; do echo -n '--------- '; done; echo
 )\
  | column -nt

echo "Average: $(grep -o '201[1-4].[0-9]\+' $myfiles | datamash -s -t: mean 2)"

$ ./mktable.sh file*.txt
file1.txt  file2.txt  file3.txt
---------  ---------  ---------
2012.69    2013.17    2013.54
2013.44    2012.6     2013.9
2012.64    2013.12    2013.66
2013.11    2012.76    2013.44
2012.6     2013.75    2013.89
2012.41    2013.08    2013.62
2012.41               2013.41
2013.2                
---------  ---------  ---------  
n=8        n=6        n=7        
---------  ---------  ---------  
Average: 2013.1638095238
```

Comment: This is resulting in `datamash: invalid numeric value in line 5 field 2: '2012.6 '` in the command line. I'm not sure there is a fifth line? A bit confused

Comment: Nice, I need to check out `datamash` in more detail...

Comment: @geom I ran into the same problem, that's why I added the `sed`-statement.  Probably a copy-pasting issue between your data, and tabs getting lost in your post or somesuch... try `sed 's/[[:blank:]]$//'` ?

Comment: ... or change the `grep` regex to use a greedy `[0-9]+`, so blanks don’t appear in the output.

Comment: @markgraf The table works a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I would process the whole thing using AWK:

```awk
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN {
    RS = " +|\t+|\n"
    OFS = "\t"
}

$1 >= 2011 && $1 < 2015 {
    counts[FILENAME]++
    allcounts++
    allsum += $1
    values[FILENAME][length(values[FILENAME])] = $1
}

END {
    for (file in counts) {
        printf "%s%s", file, OFS
        if (counts[file] > maxlength) {
            maxlength = counts[file]
        }
    }
    printf "\n"
    for (i = 0; i < maxlength; i++) {
        for (file in counts) {
            if (i < counts[file]) {
                printf "%.2f", values[file][i]
            }
            printf "%s", OFS
        }
        printf "\n"
    }
    printf "\n"
    for (file in counts) {
        printf "n=%d%s", counts[file], OFS
    }
    printf "\n"
    printf "Average: %f\n", allsum / allcounts
}
```

Save this to a file (for example `546830`), make it executable (`chmod 755 546830`), and run it as follows:

```
./546830 file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

You can line the columns up using `column`:

```
./546830 file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt | column -t
```

Using the examples given in your question, I get

```
file1.txt  file3.txt    file2.txt
2012.69    2013.54      2013.17
2013.44    2013.90      2012.60
2012.64    2013.66      2013.12
2013.11    2013.44      2012.76
2012.60    2013.89      2013.75
2012.41    2013.62      2013.08
2012.41    2013.41      
2013.20                 
n=8        n=7          n=6
Average:   2013.163810
```

The order of files in the output won’t necessarily match their order on input, but the values won’t get mixed up. If the order is important I can change the script to preserve it.

The way this works is to split each file up into records on spaces and newlines, then store each record which meets the criteria (between 2011 included and 2015 excluded) in the `values` array, indexed by file name and count. The values are also added to the `allsum` accumulator, and a per-file count is kept in the `counts` array and an aggregate count in the `allcounts` accumulator.

Comment: I used `nano` to save it to a file and then replaced "FILENAME" with the name I had given it. When I executed the script it is saying "Permission denied".

Comment: `chmod 755` followed by your filename will make the script executable.

Comment: Sorry I'm trying my best but I'm a beginner really. `chmod 755 ./FILENAME file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt | column -t` has made all the files executable. Then I tried just `./FILENAME` but it says there are syntax errors on lines 11 and 30

Comment: No need to apologise, we were all beginners at some point! `chmod 755 FILENAME` would have been enough, but that doesn’t matter now. Did you copy and paste the script, or did you type it in manually?

Comment: I copied and pasted it

Comment: Sorry, I’m using Gawk extensions, so the first line should really be `#!/usr/bin/gawk -f`. Could you change that and try again? Or equivalently, without changing the script, run `gawk -f FILENAME file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt` (after installing `gawk` if necessary — use your package manager).

Comment: Ah! That did run but the output was ```file2.txt 
2013.17 

n=1 
Average: 2013.170000
``` There are definitely more than one in the second file

Comment: OK, that suggests your files are using tabs as separators; I’ve fixed the script to handle that (the `RS =` line in the `BEGIN` block).

Comment: It worked! Thank you for your help, I've learned a lot